# Change chapter format in amsbook

Tags: chapters, amsbook

I'm using `amsbook` documentclass, but the format of chapter title looks like

> CHAPTER 1
>
> Preliminaries on A-theory

(in two lines), which I don't like. I want to change it to

> Chapter 1. Preliminaries on A-theory

or

> Chapter 1
>
> Preliminaries on A-theory

(in two lines).

Also, the format of proof is in `textsc` which I don't like, I want it to be like "*Proof*" as in `amsart` documentclass.

Is there an easy way to fix these problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One just needs to patch the relevant pieces in `\@makechapterhead` and `\proof`

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\uppercase\@xp}{}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\proof}{\scshape}{\itshape}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{foo}
Bar baz
\begin{proof}
bla bla bla
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A solution with `etoolbox` is possible too, but the second bit would be difficult, because the `proof` environment takes an optional argument. One might resort to evil trickery like

```
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname\string\proof\endcsname{\scshape}{\itshape}{}{}
```

but avoiding this kind of stuff is precisely one of the reasons `xpatch` was written.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot!

Comment: Is it easy to change "Chapter 1" to boldface "Chapter 1" (to be of the same looking as the text in chapter title? If this is easy to do, please to add it also in your answer.

Comment: @Lao-tzu not nice but `\xpatchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\mdseries\uppercase\@xp}{\bfseries}{}{}` should do.

Comment: Thanks, quite good, but the "Chapter 1" is smaller than the size of the text in chapter title.

Comment: It was also before, but with uppercase you did't notice it. `\xpatchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\normalsize\mdseries\uppercase\@xp}{\bfseries\fontsize{\@xivpt}{18}}{}{}`.

Comment: Now it's perfect, thank you very much!